# Tap Push Notifications : can't be directed to specific ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I'm working on app that includes a messenger feature ,the problem is every time i tap on the push notification im directed to the app itself rather than the message itself, i believe the code is correct, might it be a matter of swift version ....?

// AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
   let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("messageID: \(messageID)")
    }

    connectToFirebase()
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    if let dictString = userInfo["gcm.notification.customData"] as? String {
        print("dictString \(dictString)")
        if let dict = convertToDictionary(text: dictString) {
            if let uid = dict["userId"] as? String,
                let fullname = dict["username"] as? String,
                let email = dict["email"] as? String,
                let profileImageUrl = dict["profileImageurl"] as? String {

                let user = User(uid: uid, fullname: fullname, email: email, profileImageurl: profileImageUrl, status: "")

                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let chatVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: IDENTIFIER_CHAT) as! ChatViewController

                chatVC.partnerUserName = user.fullname
                chatVC.partnerId = user.uid
                chatVC.partnerUser = user


                guard let currentVC = UIApplication.topViewController() else {
                    return
                }

                currentVC.navigationController?.pushViewController(chatVC, animated: true)


            }
        }
    }
```

Extentions

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }
        return controller
    }
}
```